# Binomial Zero Probability Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, binomial-distribution

Let's assume a histogram of $K$ cells and $N$ samples. In some bins, the counts are zero, $k(i)$ $i \in [1,K]$. How can I test the probability is really zero (Bayesian) or alternatively what is the p-value of H0: p(i)>0.

Comment: Tell us more about the data. What is it? Are the bins fixed, predefined or data-based? Do I understand correctly that $\sum_i k(i) = N$? How was the data gathered?